# How to fold and cut a rectangular paper into a double overlapped square with maxium area?

Tags: geometry

As stated in the title. To be more clear, my requirement is that, one can fold the paper, but also cut, leave a square paper which is 2-folded. And one can use ruler, i.e. the size of the paper is known. Also one can use scissor so that the unfolded part could be removed.
Take a simple case, a rectangular whose long side is over two times of short side. Then one can just fold along the long side at the position one times of the short side, then cut the unfolded part, leaving a perfect square. However, if the long side is very long, meaning the cut part is large. I wonder whether there exists other ways to utilize these part to obtain a larger double-folded square? 
Maybe the restriction is too strong. Any one are welcome to give more general discussion with other restrictions.

Comment: If you're allowing cutting, then you will always be able to achieve a square whose area is half of the area of the original piece of paper.

Comment: Do you want to cut out of your original rectangle a whole rectangle which you can fold in half to give a square? Or do you want to cut out a square and cover it with pieces cut out from the original rectangle? Or do you want to cut out a piece which you can fold in some way to give a square which has double thickness? Or do you want @vadim123's idea which is to dissect the rectangle into two equal squares neither of which may be intact. At the moment your question is rather ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

No. If only folding and cutting is allowed the cut portion of the rectangle cannot be reused... On the other hand if gluing the cut portion in allowed then the square's area can be increased... And the maximum area of the square will  be the half the area of the rectangle... This is because if gluing is not allowed the only square that can be produced is the one with the side length equal to the smallest side of the rectangle.. I hope you are convinced